# How to use the ElasticSearch Java API to build an Aggregation from JSON

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

My code has an ElasticSearch query and aggregations in JSON format, and wants to call the ElasticSearch Java API.

For the Query portion, I can use WrapperQuery to build the query from the JSON as so:

```
val query = Json.obj(
  "query_string" -> Json.obj("query" -> "*"))

val aggs = Json.obj(
  "gender" -> Json.obj("terms" -> Json.obj("field": "gender")),
  "age"    -> Json.obj("terms" -> Json.obj("field": "age")))

val aggsRequestBuilder = new SearchRequestBuilder(client)
  .setIndices(index())
  .setQuery(QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(query.toString())
  .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.???(aggs.toString())
```

But then, I also have the JSON for the aggregations and I don't see an AggregationsBuilder.wrapperAggregation() function that I can use to build aggregations object from JSON.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered the answer, undocumented.  The byte[] overload of setAggregations() will accept JSON.  I hope this is helpful to others.

```
val aggsRequestBuilder = new SearchRequestBuilder(client)
  .setIndices(index())
  .setQuery(QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(query.toString())
  .setAggregations(agg.toString().getBytes())
```

Comment: How to do this using `RestHighLevelClient` in E.S 5.6?